# Can you step "1.00" instead of just 1 in input type number?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

I'm using Polymer paper-input and I want to make my input of `type="number"` always show 2 decimals points, including when it's a whole number.

So instead of the default of just `1`, I want to always show it as `1.00`. I got the paper-input to `step="1"` or even `step="0.01"`, but every time the value is a whole number, it won't show `1.00`

```
<paper-input id="taxPercent" min="0" max="99" step="1.00" on-change="_onVariablesChanged" value="0.00"> Tax Percent</paper-input>
```

```
_onVariablesChanged: function (event){
 let value = event.target.value; 
 value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `min=0.00` and `max=99.99`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the input is updated, check if a `.` is found in the value.

- If that's the case, no need to change something.
- If not, append `.00` at the end.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', update);
});

function update() {
  if (/\./.test(this.value) === false) {
    this.value = `${this.value}.00`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

Comment: This works, but in regular input. Paper-input component's behaviors prevent .00 to show when it's a whole number. So I just opt in with the regular input.

Answer (score 3):

You could use event listener to detect when the value changes. `input.value` will be a string, but adding a `+` will convert it to a number. Numbers have the `toFixed()` method ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) that formats numbers to contain a certain number of decimal precision.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', () =>
  input.value = (+input.value).toFixed(2));
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1">
```

Comment: is there a way to do it by input id insteat of query selector?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#my-input-id')`